# Using listed YAML variables for Jinja templating

Tags: ansible, jinja2

So I can't seem to find my way round this frustrating problem and I'm wondering if anyone on here has any ideas.
I have a Jinja template that spits out a long list of IP address in a config file format. This works fine. The issue is that when I have a customer with more than one IP address stored to their name the template, rather than saving this new ip on a new line, simply appends the second IP on to the first one and puts out one line with two IP addresses joined together. This is of course not ideal.
Below is the Jinja template I am using:

```
{% for cust, config in customers.items()%}
{% raw %}#{% endraw %} {{ cust }} - {{ config['type'] }}
-A INPUT -s {{ config['ipaddr'] }} -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport {{config['accept']}} ACCEPT
{% endfor %}
```

And this is the variables file from which the template is taking the values:

```
BTG-VELOCITY:
    type: PBSTP
    accept: 32500
    connect: 33500
    ipaddr: 
      196.167.203.65
      192.167.203.65
    subtype: OUTBOUND
GFAM:
    type: SPOT
    accept: 32501
    connect: 33501
    ipaddr: 192.168.563.20
    subtype: AMOUNT
GUANFABANK:
    type: SPOT
    accept: 32503
    connect: 33503
    ipaddr: 192.168.563.40
    subtype: STACKED
MAINBANK:
    type: FWD
    accept: 32504
    connect: 33504
    ipaddr: 192.167.203.02
    subtype: TIERED
TEST-BANK:
    type: PBSTP
    accept: 32506
    connect: 33506
    ipaddr: 192.167.203.92
    subtype: INBOUND
SESH:
    type: SPOT
    accept: 32508
    connect: 33508
    ipaddr: 192.167.203.63
    subtype: TIERED
```

The issue is with the customer 'BTG-VELOCITY'. The template spits out one line like this

```
-A INPUT -s 192.168.563.20 196.168.563.20 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 32501 ACCEPT
```

Rather than the desired two lines like this:

```
-A INPUT -s 192.168.563.20 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 32501 ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 196.168.563.20 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 32501 ACCEPT
```

Comment: Why not add nested for loop to iterate over ip addresses?

Comment: I tried this but I was possibly doing it wrong. When I did it ended up making a huge output file with way too many entries and every client having the same IP address value on each line. Is there any chance you can suggest how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why you would expect your template to output two lines. You only have a single loop, and it loops once per "customer".  If you want to generate multiple lines of output for each customer block, you're going to need another loop.

In most cases you have something like:

```
ipaddr: 192.167.203.63
```

For your BTG-VELOCITY customer, you have:

```
ipaddr: 196.167.203.65 192.167.203.65
```

So if you split the value of `ipaddr` on whitespace, you'll get a list of addresses.  That would let you do something like this:

```
{% for cust, config in customers.items()%}
{% raw %}#{% endraw %} {{ cust }} - {{ config['type'] }}
{% for ipaddr in config['ipaddr'].split() %}
-A INPUT -s {{ ipaddr }} -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport {{config['accept']}} ACCEPT
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

That will get you what you want.

From a data structure perspective, you might want to make `ipaddr` a list, as in:

```
BTG-VELOCITY:
    type: PBSTP
    accept: 32500
    connect: 33500
    ipaddr: 
      - 196.167.203.65
      - 192.167.203.65
    subtype: OUTBOUND
GFAM:
    type: SPOT
    accept: 32501
    connect: 33501
    ipaddr: 
192.168.563.20
    subtype: AMOUNT
```

This makes it obvious that is a multi-valued attribute, and it means you no longer need to `split` the value:

```
{% for cust, config in customers.items()%}
{% raw %}#{% endraw %} {{ cust }} - {{ config['type'] }}
{% for ipaddr in config['ipaddr'] %}
-A INPUT -s {{ ipaddr }} -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport {{config['accept']}} ACCEPT
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the silly questions. Still quick new to Jinja.